# round a floating-point number to the next integer value in java

Tags: java, integer, floating-point, rounding

how can i round up a floating point number to the next integer value in Java? Suppose

> 2.1         -->3
>
> 3.001       -->4
>
> 4.5         -->5
>
> 7.9         -->8

Comment: java.lang.Math.ceil?

Comment: Thanks ...same happened to me as well..`(int)Math.ceil(i/j)` where `i,j are int` ...if `i/j` was `2.1` it returned me `2` instead of `3` as expected by `Math.ceil`. however, if I kept `j` as a `double` it worked as expected.

Comment: Hey Vikram, this happens because division between integers returns an integer. It's a bit weird at first it it's how it works. If you want decimals one of the sides of the division must be a float or double

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should look at ceiling rounding up in java's math packages: Math.ceil

---

EDIT: Added the javadoc for Math.ceil. It may be worth reading all the method in Math.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29

> `public static double ceil(double a)`
>
> Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that
>   is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a
>   mathematical integer. Special cases:
>
> - If the argument value is already equal to a mathematical integer, then the result is the same as the argument.
> - If the argument is NaN or an infinity or positive zero or negative zero, then the result is the same as the argument.
> - If the argument value is less than zero but greater than -1.0, then the result is negative zero.
>
> Note that the value of `Math.ceil(x)` is exactly the value of
>   `-Math.floor(-x)`.

Comment: Math.ceil(2.1) will produce 3.

Comment: Math.ceil(3.4) gives value 3 only. I want the value to be 4. How can i do that?

Comment: Doesnt for me... 
groovy> Math.ceil(3.4) 
 
Result: 4.0
Are you performing some other calculations on this result which might be dropping precision then casting to an int?

Comment: As `Math.ceil` return a double and you asked for an integer, you should rather first convert it to a `Double` and then get its integer value: `new Double(Math.ceil(3.4)).intValue()` or even `(int)Math.ceil(3.4)`

Answer (score 24):

try this

```
float a = 4.5f;

int d = (int) Math.ceil(a);

System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue where I was still getting the smaller int value. It was the division, not the Math.ceil. You have to add a (float) cast to the ints. This is how I fixed it:

```
int totalNumberOfCachedData = 201;
int DataCountMax = 200;

float ceil =(float) totalNumberOfCachedData / (float)DataCountMax;
int roundInt = (int) Math.ceil(ceil);
```

This will give me 2 for the value of roundInt.

Comment: Exactly what I need.

Comment: If you want this for dividing integers, you can use `x/y rounded up` = `(x+y-1) / y`.  No need to convert both to floating-point and back.  32-bit `float` can't exactly represent every 32-bit `int`, so this way isn't even safe for large numbers: for `(2^30 + 1) / 2^30`, you'd get 1 instead of 2 because the numerator would round down when converting to the nearest representable float.

Answer (score 8):

See

```
float a=10.34f,b=45.678f;

System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(a));
System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(b));
```

Output

```
11
46
```

Comment: Math.ceil(5/2) is 2.0 it should be 3 ??

Comment: @GaneshP : It is because both `5` and `2` are regarded as integers. Hence, integer arithmetic comes into play. Diving them as you said, `Math.ceil(5/2)` would yield an integer result which is `2` (integers cannot accommodate a fractional part) hereby `2` is passed as an argument to the `cell()` method which then yields `2` - ceiling of `2` is `2.0` as obvious. If you instead had made one or both of them either `float` or `double` then, you would have indeed seen `3.0` such as `Math.ceil(5/2D)`, `Math.ceil(5D/2D)`, `Math.ceil(5/2F)`, `Math.ceil(5F/2F)` or even `Math.ceil(5.0/2.0)` etc.

Answer (score 3):

If it helps someone, here's how I get this working:

```
int arraySize = 3;
int pageSize = 10;
int pagesQty = (int) Math.ceil(arraySize / (float) pageSize);

System.out.println(pagesQty);

//Displays 1
```

Divisor must be a float in order to work properly.

Comment: If you want this for dividing integers, you can use `x/y rounded up` = `(x+y-1) / y`.  No need to convert both to floating-point and back.  32-bit `float` can't exactly represent every 32-bit `int`, so this way isn't even safe for large numbers: it might round `arraySize` down when converting to the nearest representable float.  Also, if you really had a virtual memory page it would be a power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
public static int roundDoubleToUpperInt(double d){
    return (d%1==0.0f)?(int)d:(int)(d+1);
}
```

Comment: FP remainder is expensive to compute accurately.  This looks like a terrible idea unless you have some evidence that this compiles more efficiently than `Math.ceil`, or has any advantage.  Also, why do the `+1` *before* converting to integer?  Conditional integer add can be cheap with `cmov`.