# How to round a double to closest even number

Tags: java, math

I want to round a double value to the next even integer number. e.g.:

- 489.5435 to 490
- 2.7657 to 2

I've tried `Math.rint()`, but it gives me 489 instead of 490.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [round a floating-point number to the next integer value in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753959/round-a-floating-point-number-to-the-next-integer-value-in-java)

Comment: Why does `489.5435` get promoted to the next integer value but `2.7657` gets only the integral part evaluated?

Comment: have yuou tried `Math.ceil(double)'?

Comment: By "next straight number" do you mean closest even number?

Comment: yes, i need an even number (x%y=0).

Comment: sry for my english ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply:

```
public static long roundEven(double d) {
    return Math.round(d / 2) * 2;
}
```

Gives:

```
System.out.println(roundEven(2.999));  // 2 
System.out.println(roundEven(3.001));  // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Math.ceil(...)`

```
int roundToNextEven(double d) {
    int hlp = (int)Math.ceil(d);
    if (hlp%2 == 0)
        return hlp;
    return hlp-1;
}
```

The idea is that if the next ceiling float is not even, we must round to floor instead of rounding to ceil.

You can also use `Math.floor(...)` .. the only difference is that you have to round to ceil (add 1 to the result) if the floor is not even

```
int roundToNextEven(double d) {
    int hlp = (int)Math.floor(d);
    if (hlp%2 == 0)
        return hlp;
    return hlp+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double foo = 3.7754;
int nextEven;

if (((int)foo)%2 == 0)
    nextEven = (int)foo;
else
    nextEven = ((int)foo) + 1;
```

will probably do what you need

Comment: @MuratK. yes it does... it gives 4 as wanted. He doesn't want the number to be rounded but he wants to get the next even number ^^

Comment: @MuratK. according to the SO 2.7657 shall become 2. So 4.8 should become 4... That's the closest even number to 4.8

Comment: unfortunately i'm not allowed to use if/else yet. we "dont know it yet". University, first semster..

Comment: @Jannis then you should have a look at Jean Logeart's answer! he can do it without if/else ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
extension DoubleExt on double {
  ///
  ///round the number to its nearest even integer
  double roundToEven() => (this / 2).round() * 2;
}
```

then use like this:

```
28.9.roundToEven() => 28.0
25.00448.roundToEven() => 26.0
```