# How to adjust floating part to next integer value

Tags: java, android

For my application I have a requirement to convert and adjust a floating number to nearest integer.

For example

5.430 to 5

5.767 to 6

4.32 to 4

How can I archive this in android??

I have already used math.ceil() and math.nextup() function,. But it is not working

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753959/round-a-floating-point-number-to-the-next-integer-value-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [round a floating-point number to the next integer value in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753959/round-a-floating-point-number-to-the-next-integer-value-in-java)

Comment: @Frédéric,  my question is not a duplicate of the link that  you mentioned. My requirements is round my float part to integer if the floting part is greater than .5  But if we use math.ceil () then the float part will change to next integer even if the input is 3.0001   it is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Math#round(float a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)) will round the float to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MathDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // get two double numbers
      double x = 60984.1;
      double y = -497.99;
   double x1 = 125.9;
  double y1 = 0.4873;

  // call ceal for these these numbers
  System.out.println("Math.ceil(" + x1 + ")=" + Math.ceil(x1));
  System.out.println("Math.ceil(" + y1 + ")=" + Math.ceil(y1));
  System.out.println("Math.ceil(-0.65)=" + Math.ceil(-0.65));


      // call floor and print the result
      System.out.println("Math.floor(" + x + ")=" + Math.floor(x));
      System.out.println("Math.floor(" + y + ")=" + Math.floor(y));
      System.out.println("Math.floor(0)=" + Math.floor(0));
   }
}
```